# CodeIgniter - What kind of variable can work during controller is called?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**The first thing I want to ask is how does controller work?** Assuming that I have a controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public static $groupId;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('product_model');

        $data['new_products'] = $this->product_model->get_new_products();
        $data['featured_products'] = $this->product_model->get_featured_products();
        $data['sale_products'] = $this->product_model->get_sale_products();

        $data['template'] = 'index';
        $data['title'] = 'Home';

        $this->load->view('master', $data);
    }

    public function group($groupId) {
        $this->load->model('group_model');
        $this->load->model('product_model');

        $groupId = array_pop(explode('-', $groupId));
        self::$groupId = $groupId;

        $data['groupName'] = $this->group_model->get_group_name($groupId);
        $data['allGroupWithQuantity'] = $this->group_model->get_group_with_quantity();
        $data['products'] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_group($groupId);

        $data['template'] = 'group';
        $data['title'] = $data['groupName']->groupName;

        $this->load->view('master', $data);
    }

    public function test() {
        echo seft:$groupId;
    }

}

/* End of file home.php */
/* Location: ./application/modules/front/controllers/home.php */
```

When I access `http://localhost:8080/ci/` and `http://localhost:8080/ci/television` and then type `http://localhost:8080/ci/test/`, I get white screen. If in the first time controller is called (use method in controller), and in the second time, I think controller don't need reload so from group method, I set value for $groupId and in the test method I can get it easy but I can't. Maybe when I call test method, controller is reloaded.

**The second thing I want to ask, how to pass $groupId through other method?** Remember! $groupId doesn't store in controller, I get it from url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your controller like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/ci/home/group/12
```

where 12 is your groupid and home is the name of your controller. Use a session for storing your $groupId in the group function:

```
$this->CI->session->set_userdata('groupId', $groupId);
```

To load your $groupId in test use this line of code:

```
$groupId = $this->CI->session->userdata('groupId');
```

Another solution is (as requested) although it is not best practice, to make a static class called group:

```
<?php 
class Group
{
public static $groupId = 12;


}?>
```

Then your homecontroller will look like this:

```
include_once 'group.php';
class Home extends CI_Controller {



public function __construct() {

}
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('product_model');

    $data['new_products'] = $this->product_model->get_new_products();
    $data['featured_products'] = $this->product_model->get_featured_products();
    $data['sale_products'] = $this->product_model->get_sale_products();

    $data['template'] = 'index';
    $data['title'] = 'Home';

    $this->load->view('master', $data);
}
public function group($groupId) {
    $this->load->model('group_model');
    $this->load->model('product_model');

    $groupId = array_pop(explode('-', $groupId));
    Group::$groupId = $groupId;

    $data['groupName'] = $this->group_model->get_group_name($groupId);
    $data['allGroupWithQuantity'] = $this->group_model->get_group_with_quantity();
    $data['products'] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_group($groupId);

    $data['template'] = 'group';
    $data['title'] = $data['groupName']->groupName;

    $this->load->view('master', $data);
}
public function test() {

    echo Group::$groupId;
}

}
?>
```

For more information on controllers check this site:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: I know that. I always can take $groupId from url localhost:8080/cifirst/telephone-1.html. I accept your answer but sorry, I don't want to use session. I see in asp.net mvc, if I do like this in controller: private static string keyword; public static string Keyword
        {
            get { return keyword; }
            set { keyword = value; }
        } and if I assign Keyword with any value, example groupId in group method, I can refresh the page but Keyword value doesn't lost. I want to do this.